# Numbering theorem in microsoft word with field

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to make theorem numbering in microsoft word 2010. I use field to make theorem numbering, as below.

Insert -> Quick Parts -> Field

[image]

The output is

[image]

Now I want to make numbering :

> Theorem numberchapter.numbertheorem.

as example:

> Theorem 1.2.

What the field codes to make that theorem numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Word expects you to create this kind of number like this:

You choose one of the built-in Heading styles (Heading 1, Heading 2 etc.) to be your "Chapter heading" style, and you apply the numbering that you want in the Theorem captions. For example, you might choose Heading 1 or Heading 2. Let's say you choose Heading 2, and you make its outnumbering look like "1" or "1."

You go to *References*->*Insert Caption*.

In the *Label* dropdown, select "Theorem". If "Theorem" isn't there, you can add it using the *New Label...* button.

Click the *Numbering...* button. In the *Format* dropdown, ensure that "1.,2.,3., ..." is selected.

Check the *Include chapter number* box.

Select "Heading 2" in the *Chapter starts with style* dropdown

Select ".  (period)" in the *Use separator* dropdown

Click OK etc.

Word then inserts text and field codes like this:

```
Theorem { STYLEREF 2 \s }.{ SEQ Theorem \* Arabic \s 2 }
```

The { STYLEREF 2 \s } means "insert the numbering from the most recent paragraph with style "Heading 2" (As far as I can remember, Word does not actually document that "2" can be used instead of "Heading 2", but it can be important if you have to internationalise your document).

The { SEQ Theorem * Arabic \s 2 } inserts the next figure number, restarting at the Heading 2 paragraph style.

It is generally best if you can do things exactly the way that Word would do them, because then there is a reasonable guarantee that when you use other cross-referencing facilities such as tables of Theorems and so on, they will work as you expect.

In this case, Word does not provide a built-in mechanism for inserting the final "." that you have in your Theorem numbers. If possible, I would omit that ".". If not, you can add it manually so you have

```
Theorem { STYLEREF 2 \s }.{ SEQ Theorem \* Arabic \s 2 }.
```

That assumes that you want to restart the Theorem numbering in each new chapter. If instead you want Theorem numbers like this

1.1.
1.2.
1.3.
2.4.
2.5.
3.6. etc.

then all you need do is omit the "\s 2" from the SEQ field.

There are other ways that you could use fields to provide this kind of sequencing, if, for example, you used a { SEQ Chapter } field to number your chapter headings rather than outnumbering, you might use something like

{ SEQ Chapter }.{ SEQ Theorem \r 0 \h } in each Chapter heading, then

```
Theorem { SEQ Chapter \c }.{ SEQ Theorem \* Arabic }.
```

for each Theorem.